# Android SDK Timer Not Working

Tags: android, timer, crash, clock, stopwatch

I have been coding a timer on my app so that when you hit a button the text displays a time which counts up in 0.1 second increments.

I though i coded it right but it turns out the app crashes whenever i hit the ready button on my phone... Could someone give me a hint as to what is going wrong. I think it could be something with starting the timer?

My OnCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_double_player);

    Button readyBtn =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.readyBtn);



    readyBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0) {



            Button readyBtn =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.readyBtn);
            Spinner selectorLeft = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selectorLeft);
            Spinner selectorRight = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selectorRight);
            ImageView narLeft = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.narwhalleft);
            ImageView narRight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.narwhalRight);


            selectorLeft.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
            selectorRight.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
            readyBtn.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);

            final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerText);
            final Handler handler;
            text.setText(0);


            handler = new Handler();

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
                boolean ready = true;
                int number = 0;

                @Override
                public void run(){
                    while(ready){
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                            }
                        catch(InterruptedException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        handler.post(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run(){
                                number+=0.1;
                                text.setText(String.valueOf(number));
                                }
                            });
                    }
                }
            };
            new Thread(runnable).start();

            narRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    int clicksNeeded = 100;
                    boolean rightWon = false;
                    int clicksClickedRight = 0;

                    clicksClickedRight = clicksClickedRight + 1;

                    if(clicksClickedRight == clicksNeeded){

                        rightWon = true;
                        }
                    if(rightWon == true){


                    }

                }


            });

            narLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    int clicksNeeded = 100;
                    boolean leftWon = false;
                    int clicksClickedLeft = 0;

                    clicksClickedLeft = clicksClickedLeft + 1;

                    if(clicksClickedLeft == clicksNeeded){

                        leftWon = true;
                        }
                    if(leftWon == true){


                    }

                }
            });


        }
    });


}
```

Comment: post the stack trace and it looks like you have a few miss placed `{` brakects

Comment: post the logCat from the point your app crashes till the end.

Comment: What does your LogCat say (you should get a bunch of red error messages showing when your app crashes)? If you can, also use the debugger to step through (set a breakpoint on the first statement in your readyBtn click listener). That will help you zone in on the exact statement causing the error which will also allow us to help you more effectively.

Comment: The biggest mistake you made is initializing all the pointers inside your readyBtn.onClickListener() method. Especially reinitializing the readyBtn pointer.

Comment: and you can use a handler instead of thread

Comment: @NitroNbg  Sorry cannot post log cat as the emulator doesn't work on my pc so i export the app to my phone

Comment: @NitroNbg moved all the refs out of the method now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a problem in your line:

```
text.setText(0);
```

The declaration of function is `setText(int resid)` so it tries to search for a string resource with id `0` and no will be found, stack trace error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
```

So replace your line with:

```
text.setText(String.valueOf(0));
```

Second thing, you have declared your number variable as int:

```
int number = 0;
```

But, you're adding a float number to it:

```
number+=0.1;
```

So declare it `float number = 0;`.

To round up your number to one decimal place use this trick with mutliplying the number first, converting it to int to strip away decimal places and converting it back to float:

```
float displaynumber = (float)((int)(number * 10.0))/10.0f;
```

Comment: Thanks this is what aused it to crash but now it doesnt update it just stays at 0

Comment: Check out my new suggestion, i can now observe number showed by TextView `text` changing.

Comment: DUH!!! of course it needs to be a float, i am a fool thanks for the answer but now i get a number with 5 decimals, is this something to do with cast time?

Comment: That's pretty normal for float types... they don't store value in decimal but in a binary... a value 0.1 cannot be represented precisely as 0.1, so you'll get for exampple many 0.999999 or something similiar, you have to find out how to round it. Can i get a green check mark? :)

Comment: check out new suggestion